# React-native webview issue in SDK 33 update

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent` from `\node_modules\react-native-webview\lib\RNCWebViewNativeComponent.js`: Module `react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
   at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
   at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
   at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
   at Object.resolve (\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:264:42)
   at \node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31
   at Array.map ()
   at resolveDependencies (\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
   at \node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
   at Generator.next ()
   at asyncGeneratorStep (\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
   BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░ 71.7% (1763/2082), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [23/Oct/2023:11:10:20 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"